# ibping error: “can't serve class 50 on this port”

Tags: ping, infiniband

I try to run an ibping server on a machine with an infiniband card:

```
ibping -S
```

I get this error message:

```
ibping: iberror: failed: can't serve class 50 on this port
```

Any idea to solve the problem? For information, the infiniband cable is apparently broken (`ibstat` shows that all ports are in physical state `polling`), but I do not think it should make the previous command fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally restarted the computer, now `ibping -S` seems to work. Still no idea on why it was broken.